# How to get server timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone

I want to set different timezone in Javascript.Currently It is showing date and time zone of local machine or client's PC date /timezone.

Regards,

Answer (score 7):

Javascript is a client-side language and does not interact with the server that way. You'll need to fetch that data from your server-side platform.

Here is some PHP code to get the data you are looking for. You'll either need to put this in your page and echo the result into a JS variable....

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
    $tz = $date->getTimezone();
    $tzone = $tz->getName();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeZone='<?php echo $tzone ?>';
</script>
```

---

....or keep the PHP  page separate, and fetch the data using AJAX

---

**getTimeZone.php**

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
    $tz = $date->getTimezone();
    echo $tz->getName();
?>
```

**JS**

```
var timeZone=null;
$.get('getTimeZone.php', function(result){
    timeZone=result;
}, 'html');
//I know this is jQuery, not JS, but you get the idea.
```

Comment: dont know why this was voted down... I voted this up because this is the right answer

Comment: Thanks, `Michael Koper`. I was wondering the same thing myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no in-built functionality in JavaScript to do this.

You could embed the time-zone in (e.g.) a hidden field on the page when it is rendered from the server, or implement some sort of http request to actively retrive it from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to include the timezone in the server's response or to make an ajax call from the javascript browser client to the server to get the server's timezone.