# How to set the today's date of 'date control' according to the time-zone set on server using jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, timezone

I'm using PHP, jQuery/JavaScript on my website.

For showing and selecting the date on a form in a "Date Control" I'm using one library titled **jquery.dateLists.min.js**

The issue I'm facing is with the time-zone on server is `America/Los_Angeles` but the script is setting the default today's date of the date control according to the time-zone `Asia/Calcutta` which is the time-zone set on my local machine.

How to set the today's date according to the time-zone set on server i.e. according to the time-zone `America/Los_Angeles`

Following is the HTML and script which sets the current date according to the time-zone `Asia/Calcutta`.

**HTML code:**

**jQuery code to call the function :**

```
$('#reg_date').dateDropDownsforRebate({dateFormat:'mm-dd-yy'});
```

**The URL of the below library is as follows :**

http://www.amdonnelly.co.uk/things/date-drop-down-lists.aspx

**Javacript code from library file :**

```
(function(a){a.fn.dateDropDowns=function(k){var g={dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",monthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],yearStart:"1914",yearEnd:"2000"},k=a.extend(g,k);return this.each(function(){function l(){var c=d.getMonth()+1,p="",f=1;_daysInMonth=m(c,d.getFullYear())+1;a("#"+e+"_list").children().length<_daysInMonth?f=a("#"+e+"_list").children().length+1:a("#"+e+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=f;_x<_daysInMonth;_x++)c=d.getDate()==_x?"selected='true'": "",p+="<option value='"+_x+"' "+c+">"+_x+"</option>";a("#"+e+"_list").append(p)}function m(c,a){var d=31;c==4||c==6||c==9||c==11?d=30:c==2&&(d=a%4==0?29:28);return d}function n(){var c=d.getDate(),a=d.getMonth()+1,f=d.getFullYear(),b=g.dateFormat;b.indexOf("DD")>-1&&c.toString().length<2&&(c="0"+c);b.indexOf("MM")>-1&&a.toString().length<2&&(a="0"+a);b=g.dateFormat.toLowerCase();b=b.replace("dd",c);b=b.replace("mm",a);b=b.replace("yy",f);j.val(b)}var j=a(this);j.html();var b=j.attr("id")+"_dateLists", e=b+"_day",h=b+"_month",i=b+"_year",k=j.val(),d=new Date,o=g.dateFormat.indexOf("/")>-1?"/":"-";(function(){if(k.length>0){var a=g.dateFormat.split(o),b=k.split(o),f=new Date;for(_x=0;_x<b.length;_x++)a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("d")>-1?f.setDate(b[_x]):a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("m")>-1?f.setMonth(b[_x]-1):a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("y")>-1&&f.setYear(b[_x]);d=f}})();(function(){var c=g.dateFormat.split(o),d=j;j.replaceWith("<div id='"+b+"' class='dateLists_container'></div>");for(_x=0;_x<c.length;_x++)c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("d")> -1?(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+e+"' class='day_container'>"),a("#"+e).append("<select id='"+e+"_list' name='"+e+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>")):c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("m")>-1?(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+h+"' class='month_container'>"),a("#"+h).append("<select id='"+h+"_list' name='"+h+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>")):c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("y")>-1&&(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+i+"' class='year_container'>"),a("#"+i).append("<select id='"+ i+"_list' name='"+i+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>"));a("#"+b).append(d);j.hide()})();l();(function(){a("#"+h+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=0;_x<12;_x++){var c=d.getMonth()==_x?"selected='true'":"";a("#"+h+"_list").append("<option value='"+_x+"' "+c+">"+g.monthNames[_x]+"</option>")}})();(function(){a("#"+i+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=parseInt(g.yearStart);_x<parseInt(g.yearEnd)+1;_x++){var c=d.getFullYear()==_x?"selected='true'":"";a("#"+i+"_list").append("<option value='"+ _x+"' "+c+">"+_x+"</option>")}})();(function(){a("#"+e+"_list").change(function(){d.setDate(a("#"+e+"_list").val());n()});a("#"+h+"_list").change(function(){var c=parseInt(a("#"+h+"_list").val()),b=d.getDate();_daysInMonth=m(c+1,d.getFullYear());b>_daysInMonth&&(b=_daysInMonth);d=new Date(d.getFullYear(),c,b,0,0,0,0);l();n()});a("#"+i+"_list").change(function(){var b=a("#"+i+"_list").val(),e=d.getDate(),f=d.getMonth();_daysInMonth=m(f+1,b);e>_daysInMonth&&(e=_daysInMonth);d=new Date(b,f,e,0,0,0,0); l();n()})})()})}})(jQuery);

(function(a){a.fn.dateDropDownsforRebate=function(k){var g={dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",monthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],yearStart:"2014",yearEnd:"2050"},k=a.extend(g,k);return this.each(function(){function l(){var c=d.getMonth()+1,p="",f=1;_daysInMonth=m(c,d.getFullYear())+1;a("#"+e+"_list").children().length<_daysInMonth?f=a("#"+e+"_list").children().length+1:a("#"+e+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=f;_x<_daysInMonth;_x++)c=d.getDate()==_x?"selected='true'": "",p+="<option value='"+_x+"' "+c+">"+_x+"</option>";a("#"+e+"_list").append(p)}function m(c,a){var d=31;c==4||c==6||c==9||c==11?d=30:c==2&&(d=a%4==0?29:28);return d}function n(){var c=d.getDate(),a=d.getMonth()+1,f=d.getFullYear(),b=g.dateFormat;b.indexOf("DD")>-1&&c.toString().length<2&&(c="0"+c);b.indexOf("MM")>-1&&a.toString().length<2&&(a="0"+a);b=g.dateFormat.toLowerCase();b=b.replace("dd",c);b=b.replace("mm",a);b=b.replace("yy",f);j.val(b)}var j=a(this);j.html();var b=j.attr("id")+"_dateLists", e=b+"_day",h=b+"_month",i=b+"_year",k=j.val(),d=new Date,o=g.dateFormat.indexOf("/")>-1?"/":"-";(function(){if(k.length>0){var a=g.dateFormat.split(o),b=k.split(o),f=new Date;for(_x=0;_x<b.length;_x++)a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("d")>-1?f.setDate(b[_x]):a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("m")>-1?f.setMonth(b[_x]-1):a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("y")>-1&&f.setYear(b[_x]);d=f}})();(function(){var c=g.dateFormat.split(o),d=j;j.replaceWith("<div id='"+b+"' class='dateLists_container'></div>");for(_x=0;_x<c.length;_x++)c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("d")> -1?(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+e+"' class='day_container'>"),a("#"+e).append("<select id='"+e+"_list' name='"+e+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>")):c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("m")>-1?(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+h+"' class='month_container'>"),a("#"+h).append("<select id='"+h+"_list' name='"+h+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>")):c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("y")>-1&&(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+i+"' class='year_container'>"),a("#"+i).append("<select id='"+ i+"_list' name='"+i+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>"));a("#"+b).append(d);j.hide()})();l();(function(){a("#"+h+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=0;_x<12;_x++){var c=d.getMonth()==_x?"selected='true'":"";a("#"+h+"_list").append("<option value='"+_x+"' "+c+">"+g.monthNames[_x]+"</option>")}})();(function(){a("#"+i+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=parseInt(g.yearStart);_x<parseInt(g.yearEnd)+1;_x++){var c=d.getFullYear()==_x?"selected='true'":"";a("#"+i+"_list").append("<option value='"+ _x+"' "+c+">"+_x+"</option>")}})();(function(){a("#"+e+"_list").change(function(){d.setDate(a("#"+e+"_list").val());n()});a("#"+h+"_list").change(function(){var c=parseInt(a("#"+h+"_list").val()),b=d.getDate();_daysInMonth=m(c+1,d.getFullYear());b>_daysInMonth&&(b=_daysInMonth);d=new Date(d.getFullYear(),c,b,0,0,0,0);l();n()});a("#"+i+"_list").change(function(){var b=a("#"+i+"_list").val(),e=d.getDate(),f=d.getMonth();_daysInMonth=m(f+1,b);e>_daysInMonth&&(e=_daysInMonth);d=new Date(b,f,e,0,0,0,0); l();n()})})()})}})(jQuery);
```

Please help me.

Comment: please don't post the code of the library script, but a link where we can find the documentation

Comment: @Mainz007 : Here is the URL where you will get the library I'm using :http://www.amdonnelly.co.uk/things/date-drop-down-lists.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get server timezone in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742505/how-to-get-server-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: while loading that element(data drop down) fire one ajax call to server to get time and date of server.then set that values to element .

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a client based language. That means that there exists no communication between Server and JavaScript but only between your browser and JavaScript. So it can't access the given timezone from your server. It should always show the timezone your PC is in (and I guess that is Asia/Calcutta).

And looking at the plugin, I don't see a possability to set the timezone manually in the plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But tell me one thing can I set the time zone as 'America/Los_Angeles' in the above code and set the today's date according to that time zone. So it will be irrespective of the location from where the site is being accessed. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes by the method yugi said in his comment or the [duplicate link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5742576/2731055) from @webino has a good explanation